# Custom Number format in Excel table for percentage columns

Tags: excel

I have Excel data where one column is formatted to display number and other column if formatted to display values as %. In case the cell values are 0  or 0% I need to display blank cell. I know the custom format for number i.e. 0;-0;;@ however I need help for the column formatted as %. How to display blank cell when the value is 0%.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do anything special with negative numbers, you can use this:

```
0%;-0%;
```

The custom format works in three parts (in this example - Excel supports more) separated by semi-colons (`;`) :

1. Formatting for positive numbers
2. Formatting for negative numbers
3. Formatting for zero values

Some examples of this working:

```
 10% =  10%
 20% =  20%
  0% = 
-30% = -30%
```

Comment: But Let us say if it was $2,2 how to make it display blank

Comment: @Alok I'm not clear on what you mean.  In your question you've asked about how to display 0%.  If you have another question, you're better of posting another question